# Why is an F# question considered off-topic if a similar C# question exists?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706603/how-can-i-parse-numbers-written-in-english-words-into-their-numeric-equivalent-i) has been vote-closed because there is a C# version and it's "off topic".

The question asks for an F# solution (after some editing; it was originally posted poorly), and a comment by "Won't" on this (Meta) very question says it's not valid to ask F# questions because you can convert F# to C#.

Despite being the same framework, F# is not C#. F# is functional (not purely, but still, it exists separately from C# for a reason). It has features like Pattern Matching that C# does not, and this feature was even used in the answer of this question.

To me, this looks like a completely valid question, and it's already been re-opened once.

Can someone please clarify the rules around not being able to have solutions in a different language that is "a bit like" an existing answer in another language or why this question does not give an understanding of the problem and/or code? It has exactly as much information in it as the C# version, which is apparently considered fine.

Comment: Look at the close reason for an explanation.

Comment: That's probably because he is asking for code, and not showing his attempts, efforts at all.

Comment: Closed != unfixable. Actually it is a fix-it indicator

Comment: @allKid So we should vote-close every question that doesn't have any document attempts? It's not valid to ask a question if you don't know where to start? How about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653543/see-all-tables-referencing-a-primary-key

Comment: @DannyTuppeny: The close reason explains the problem and what should be fixed. I don't see what else should be added.

Comment: It is specifically to discourage [help vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) from driving quality users away.  There is a great invention that specifically helps those who don't know where to start--it's called a Search Engine.  You start typing it and it starts telling you things that are similar.  For example, if he actually did this, he would have found that this has been asked/answered multiple times already.  [Here's an example that doesn't suck](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213/convert-integers-to-written-numbers).

Comment: @Won't The only different between that question and this one, is that the example was written in a code block. I've edited this question to also have the example in a code block. Presumably now this question is valid?

Comment: @juergend This question now has a code attempt, just like the one Won't linked to. Does this meet your criteria now?

Comment: @DannyTuppeny: Not really, no.  One of the other issues with SO is that it isn't a perfect example of itself.  While effort has been made to keep this kind of thing nailed down now, there are many questions from, say, '09 and on that would violate current rules.  Better to close as dupe of an authoritative question that already has a decent answer and move on.

Comment: Can you explain this better? There is no solution in F# on that question. Why is it any more valid than this one?

Comment: @DannyTuppeny: Any decent F# programmer should be able to convert C# to F#.  Same exact framework, different syntax.  And code conversion questions ("here is code make it VB") are strictly off topic.

Comment: That is not correct. The question asks for the best way to do something in F#, and the answer is to use a feature that does not exist in C#. Converting a C# solution does not answer the question.

Answer (score 8):

This was the initial question:

> Is there a library in either .NET or Python that can, given a number in words, convert it to it's numeric equivalent or that can simply identify part of a sentence as a number in words? I'm looking at only English for now. E.g. "One Thousand Two Hundred" will be converted to 1200.

It was closed as off-topic, probably because it's asking for a library recommendation.

It was then changed to this:

> What's the easiest way in either .NET or Python to, given a number in words, convert it to it's numeric equivalent OR given a sentence, to identify part of it as a number in words? I'm looking at only English for now. E.g. "One Thousand Two Hundred" will be converted to 1200.

Now either OP is asking for a library recommendation in a sneaky way, or OP is asking for full code while having tried nothing at all. It was closed again as off-topic, this time because OP has not shown what he/she has tried.

You also went on an edit war with some other users, editing an answer into the question. It doesn't matter that the post was closed and you couldn't post an answer, you shouldn't do it.

Comment: No; the question ws completey rewritten before *any* of the last 5 close votes. I'm asking about the question in its current form, which is *exactly* how it was for all 5 of the these votes.

Comment: @DannyTuppeny It was closed with this reason: *"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."* As far as I can see, it was closed correctly. OP hasn't shown attempted solutions.

Comment: 90% of questions on SO do not; should we start vote-closing them all?

Comment: If they fit a certain close reason, then you should indeed vote to close.

Comment: @DannyTuppeny "90% of questions on SO do not" - it's a completely baseless claim and from my point of view obviously wrong. "should we start vote-closing them all?" - and yes, majority of such questions are getting closed. "SO used to be a helpful resource for people getting started." - mostly because of a huge database of questions already there, and it hasn't changed. I do not think that "write code for me" is a fine question, it will make SO into a database of college assignment solutions. It was never fine and it is not fine now.

Comment: By closing any question where the author doesn't know where to start, you're simply pushing away people that are trying to learn programming. If SO's intention is not to cater for these newbies, that's fine - but it wasn't my understanding of the goal.

Comment: SO can be whatever it wants to be. It's not a public service. Doesn't stop it being the most pathetically anal FORUM (yeah, I said it) on the web.

Comment: @DannyTuppeny SO is not designed to be a resource that will hold a user's hand through the first steps of learning to code.  It's simply not what the site was designed for, or and it doesn't have the capacity to meet that need effectively.  If that's what you need help with you're much better off taking a class, using an online tutorial designed for that task, reading a book designed to do that, etc.  SO is here to answer specific questions to specific programming problems, not to be the be all end all of programming resources.

Comment: @Servy Did you even read the question? It's not about baby syntax, it's a simple algorithm, and my solution used Pattern Matching. How is this first steps of learning to code?

Comment: @DannyTuppeny My comment was replying to your last comment, "you're simply pushing away people that are trying to learn programming".  I feel that the main question is answered quite effectively by the answer here.  Clearly this particular user is capable of making an attempt and doing some research and experimenting to at least begin to find a solution.  If he isn't willing to do that, then this simply isn't the proper site for him.

Comment: @Servy Can you please explain what the C# version of the question has additionally over this question, that shows "making an attempt"? It is a near identical question, for a different language.

Comment: The answer commented on here is incorrect. It discusses the *original* question, which was not the state when the first recent close vote was cast. The whole on-hold/close process is designed for questions to be improved. It was improved. This answer is based on completely the wrong question.

Comment: @DannyTuppeny You're correct, that other question should be closed for exactly the same reason.  That it isn't closed doesn't mean that this question should be opened, just that the other question should be closed.

Comment: @DannyTuppeny The second half of this answer most certainly applies to its current state.  It doesn't *just* discuss the first revision, it discusses the reason for the first closure *and the latest*.  Did you perhaps stop reading this answer half way through?

Comment: The *only* relevant part is "OP is asking for full code while having tried nothing at all"; and the "full code" part is an assumption. Having tried nothing is not exactly uncommon for an algorithm-based question, is it?